# Writing to Google Sheets from a Google Form using Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-editor

So I have a google form and I am processing the data from the form using script, and I ultimately want to populate this data into a spreadsheet. I've tested my code and the logger is printing all the data in the form itself, but my google sheet remains empty. I suspect I'm using the wrong code to write to sheets, but I'm not sure. I scoured through the Sheets API and it says that I can write into a sheet using `appendRow` and that I can choose which sheet to write to using `openById()`, but these do not seem to work. I would really appreciate any insights!

This is the code I have right now to write into my spreadsheet, which is not working.

```
var array1 = [id, score];  // these are 2 variables that were initialized previously 
array1 = array1.concat(array2);  
// array2 is another array that I've initialized previously which works fine
// (I've tested both of these arrays in the Logger and it prints correctly)  
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(‘SSID’); 
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Name");
sheet.appendRow(array1);
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't show how you read the data into the `array` variable. Please share all the code you are using to read from the form and writing to the spreadsheet.

Comment: `array` is simply referring to an array that I initialized previously. I've also printed `array` into the Logger and it gives me the right output, so I don't think that is the issue. I've also edited my original post to add the code for this!

Comment: Does the script throw any errors? If so can you please post them in your answer?

Answer (score 1):

So after playing around it for a while, I've realized that the fix was to simply delete the onFormSubmit trigger and then run it again. Not sure why this fixed it, but I'm assuming that it wasn't syncing/updating accurately. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Take the speech marks from around SSID, if the constant SSID is defined:

```
var SSID = 'xxxxxx';
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SSID);
```

or if you are using the ID directly:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxx');
```

Comment: Thank you! Just to clarify, do you mean to just copy the ID from the spreadsheet without the speech marks? So if the ID is abc123, do I have to write ` var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(abc123); ` ? I tried doing that but it throws up an error and it seems to be requiring the speech marks. I've also tried using double quotes " " instead, but the issue still persists '

Comment: I've updated the answer which should make it clearer. You can use either single or double speech marks.